# Maven clean failed and Maven install failed in command prompt

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to build a Maven project but everytime I clean or install the **pom.xml** of the project I'm getting the bellow error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1131]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\prosenjit\projects\CSIW Trunk 2>mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CSIW Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.479s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 08 10:12:00 IST 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.4.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
C:\prosenjit\projects\CSIW Trunk 2>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building CSIW Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.4.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.4.3.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.046s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Apr 08 10:12:47 IST 2020
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.4.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.4.3.pom -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

The pom of the project I'm using is as below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <groupId>neo.sprint.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>NeoAdv</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sprint.neo</groupId>
    <artifactId>CSIW</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CSIW Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>neo.sprint.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>LoginFramework</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added for File Upload in RIM -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
             <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
             <version>1.2.1</version> <!-- makesure correct version here -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
         <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.1-b19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-discovery/commons-discovery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/wsdl4j/wsdl4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Primefaces Theme Library -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId> <artifactId>blitzer</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.10</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- User defined jar.... installation reference CSIW\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\doc\Maven_Local_Jar.txt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Rim-FilterRules</groupId>
            <artifactId>RimFilterRules</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Rim-MergeRules</groupId>
            <artifactId>RimMergeRules</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>Rim-Validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>RimValidation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>   

        <dependency>
           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
      </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>Query-Config</groupId>
            <artifactId>QueryConfig</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.20</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>DB-Query</groupId>
            <artifactId>DBQuery</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>DB-Query</groupId>
            <artifactId>SqlDBQuery</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>DB-Query</groupId>
            <artifactId>QueryDocApproval</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  cxw debug - Added for Java13, on Tomcat 9 -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file=true</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <finalName>CSIW</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm using **Jdk-8** in my environment and below is the Maven version:

```
C:\prosenjit\projects\CSIW Trunk 2>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 23:01:09+0530)
Maven home: C:\prosenjit\software\project software\maven\apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.8.0_201, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Can anyone please help to build the project successfully? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apart from upgrading Maven as suggested in the post @JFMeier linked, you need to point JAVA_HOME to a JDK Home rather than a JRE.

Comment: It did work for me. I upgraded the maven from **3.0.3 to 3.6.0** and now the build from command prompt is successful.

Comment: Please upgrade to most recent version 3.6.3 instead of 3.6.0...furthermore I suggest to upgrade you plugins you are using maven-compiler-plugin 3.1 a little out of date...3.8.1 is uptodate...

Comment: Okay I will do that. Thanks a lot.